# Check if value exist into array field mongoid rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a groups field in mongodb database

```
"groups" : "[\"5514efcc6970640f40150100\", \"5514efcc6970640f40160100\", \"5514efcc6970640f40170100\", \"5514efcc6970640f40180100\"]
```

Please suggest the query to check if field is exist into above database array.

like `modelname.find(:groups=> 5514efcc6970640f40150100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you actually have a string in `groups`, not an array. The string looks like you called `inspect` on an array of BSON ObjectIds in Ruby and stored that stringified array in MongoDB.

The leading double quote here:

```
           ⬇
"groups" : "[\"5514efcc6970640f40150100\", ...
           ⬆
```

tells you that you have a string. Inside that string you have what looks like an array of strings but it is still a string.

If that's really what you have then I think you're stuck with regex searches (which will be slow), something like:

```
Model.where(:groups => /"5514efcc6970640f40150100"/)
```

That assumes that all your `groups` strings are consistently formed and they are really stringified arrays of hexadecimal strings.

If this is the case then I'd suggest that you immediately fix your database and code so that you use real arrays in `groups`.

---

If your `groups` really is an array of hex strings like:

```
"groups" : ["5514efcc6970640f40150100", ...
```

then you can query it like a scalar field and let MongoDB unwrap the array for you:

```
Model.where(:groups => '5514efcc6970640f40150100')
```

Comment: Thanks @mu
I got the error, actually i save the array into string datatype.